# Rollup bundle : How to read runtime environment variables from Next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables, rollup

i currently have a custom SDK bundled using rollup.js intalled on my next next.js project as a node_module

my custom SDK requires to read runtime environment variables from the next.js root directory but the usual node.env.MY_VAR does not seem to work.

is there any ways for my SDK to read runtime env?

Comment: Just a couple of quick questions. When and how is the SDK compiled (Example code?). Next.js loads ENV variables for you with  [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) maybe its just a matter of adding `require('dotenv').config()` to your SDK building script?.

Comment: @LoganAnderson I have tried that method too, did not work out, my solution was for the SDK to not read the .env directly, instead created a instance which can be called and be used in a NextJs project and set the value for the instance client-side

Comment: glad you could figure out a solution.